# How to register Converter in Spring Data Rest application

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I have Spring converter which uses Spring Data REST's component called `EnumTranslator`

```
@Component
public class TranslationStringToSpecificationStatusEnumConverter implements Converter<String, Specification.Status> {

    private final EnumTranslator enumTranslator;

    @Autowired
    public TranslationStringToSpecificationStatusEnumConverter(EnumTranslator enumTranslator) {
        this.enumTranslator = enumTranslator;
    }

    @Override
    public Specification.Status convert(String source) {
        return enumTranslator.fromText(Specification.Status.class, source);
    }
}
```

Recommended way to register such converter is to subclass `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryRestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    private final TranslationStringToSpecificationStatusEnumConverter converter;

    @Autowired
    public RepositoryRestConfig(TranslationStringToSpecificationStatusEnumConverter converter) {
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
        conversionService.addConverter(converter);
        super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
    }
}
```

When I run the Spring Boot application, it fails on the following:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
┌─────┐
|  translationStringToSpecificationStatusEnumConverter defined in file ...
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration (field java.util.List org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.configurers)
↑     ↓
|  repositoryRestConfig defined in file ...
└─────┘
```

So there is circular bean dependency.

How can I register the converter above so that I don't introduce circular bean dependency?

Comment: show EnumTranslator class

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/json/EnumTranslator.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is Spring Core specific. In order to break circle bean dependency cycle, we have to delay setting converter in `RepositoryRestConfig`. It can be achieved with setter injection:

```
@Component
public class RepositoryRestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    private TranslationStringToSpecificationStatusEnumConverter converter;

    @Override
    public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
        conversionService.addConverter(converter);
        super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setConverter(TranslationStringToSpecificationStatusEnumConverter converter) {
        this.converter = converter;
    }
}
```

You can find how to solve it in this commit by Greg Turnquist: https://github.com/pmihalcin/custom-converter-in-spring-data-rest/commit/779a6477d76dc77515b3e923079e5a6543242da2

Comment: I hadn't guess of it! Will take it into service ))

Answer (score 3):

To make it work:

```java
@Override
public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
   conversionService.addConverter(String.class, Status.class, new StringToTranslatedEnumConverter<>(Status.class));
   super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
}
```

First I created utility class that help me work with Spring beans in unmanaged objects:

```java
@Component
public final class SpringUtils {

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext ctx;

    private static SpringUtils instance;

    @PostConstruct
    private void registerInstance() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) {
        return instance.ctx.getBean(clazz);
    }
}
```

Then I created the converter:

```java
public class StringToTranslatedEnumConverter<T extends Enum<T> & TranslatedEnum> implements Converter<String, T> {

    private final ConcurrentMapCache cache;
    private EnumTranslator enumTranslator;

    private Class<T> type;

    public StringToTranslatedEnumConverter(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
        cache = new ConcurrentMapCache(type.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public T convert(String from) {

        if (enumTranslator == null) {
            enumTranslator = SpringUtils.getBean(EnumTranslator.class);
        }

        Cache.ValueWrapper wrapper = cache.get(from);
        if (wrapper != null) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) wrapper.get();
        }

        T translatedEnum = enumTranslator.fromText(type, from);
        cache.put(from, translatedEnum);
        return translatedEnum;
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

`TranslatedEnum` - it's interface-marker, used to mark enums which translation is only need.

```
public interface TranslatedEnum {
}

public enum Status implements TranslatedEnum {
    CREATED, DELETED
}
```

Comment: What is `TranslatedEnum`?

Comment: Why is `SpringUtils` class needed? Why isn't it possible to autowire `EnumTranslator` in `StringToTranslatedEnumConverter`?

Comment: @PatrikMihalčin I updated my answer... We can inject `EnumTranslator` but it will not work since we instantiate the converter using its constructor: `conversionService.addConverter(String.class, Status.class, new StringToTranslatedEnumConverter<>(Status.class));`

Comment: Thanks for the update.. your solution works.. but it is little bit hacky :) (especially the use of `SpringUtils`).. In the meantime, I received answer from Greg Turnquist: https://github.com/pmihalcin/custom-converter-in-spring-data-rest/commit/779a6477d76dc77515b3e923079e5a6543242da2

Comment: Yeah.. I've just posted it